# Vertical continuous CSS only marquee/ticker/banner with no gaps

Tags: html, css, banner, marquee, ticker

I've been attempting to convert the CSS-only horizontal marquee found here: [Ticker/Marquee Effect with No Gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483819/ticker-marquee-effect-with-no-gaps)

...into a vertical banner, without much success. Any help with this would be massively appreciated!

This is my attempt, but it isn't continuous and runs into a problem when repeating: https://codepen.io/jackwaghorn-the-decoder/pen/PoRpRwr

Code for the working horizontal marquee is

```
 <div class="ticker-wrap">
      <div class="ticker">
        <span class="item-collection-1">
          <span class="item"
            >My banner text</span
          >
        </span>
        <span class="item-collection-2">
          <span class="item"
            >My banner text</span
          >
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>


.ticker-wrap {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  height: 2.9rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
.ticker {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: marquee 60s linear infinite;
}
.item-collection-1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  animation: swap 60s linear infinite;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  color: black;
}

/* Transition */
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes swap {
  0%,
  50% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  50.01%,
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet and also show us what you have tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes here's what I have so far: https://codepen.io/jackwaghorn-the-decoder/pen/PoRpRwr